# How to make sure event won't trigger again if it hasn't stopped yet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text, effect

So, here's the thing. There's a menu bar on the side of the website. When you click on it, the menu holder rolls in from the side (the menu is opened), when you click on the bar again, the menu holder rolls back and hides the menu. Pretty simple so far. On tat bar, there is an icon with a text 'MENU'. When you open the menu, the icon changes and the text changes to 'CLOSE'. When you close the menu, it returns to normal. Still not big deal.

**This is how it looks like:**

[closed menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tAhK.png)

[opened menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q68kX.png) (the 'ZATVORIŤ' caption means 'CLOSE' don't worry about that)

Now let's get fancy. We need an **effect, a text transition** to make it look cool and smooth. So when the menu is closed, there's no caption. There's just the menu icon. The text will show when user hovers over the bar. As soon as user hovers over the bar, the 'MENU' **caption will appear letter by letter**. That means, first letter that will appear will be 'M', the second 'E'... 'N'... 'U'. The whole caption will appear in few hundred milliseconds, maybe half a second. When user hovers away, the **caption will disappear letter by latter**. So 'MEN' ... 'ME' ... 'M'... ' '. You got the point. The 'CLOSE' caption works the same way. When the user clicks on the bar (of course he needs to hover over the bar first, so there's 'MENU' caption already) the 'MENU' caption disappears letter by letter and 'CLOSE' caption will appear letter by letter. When user closes the menu, 'CLOSE' caption disappears the same way. Pretty nice thing.

**Now to the root of the whole problem.** This works as soon as the user acts normally. As soon as the user keep hovering on and away the bar too fast, it'll trigger the event while the event is already running (my best guess what the problem is). The same goes if he keeps clicking on the bar - the 'CLOSE' caption will mess up instead of 'MENU' caption. Then, **instead of letters of those captions couple of 'undefined' will appear.** So the caption would look like 'MEundefinedundefinedundefined....' or 'MMMMENundefinedundefined...' or something similar. So what I thought at first was, that it is a off-by-one error, because I got the captions saved in arrays of letters and it's showing 'undefined', right? I quickly patched it just to make sure no 'undefined' will appear - if user tries to brake it, the events just quit triggering. He can hover over the bar and nothing will happen. It'll get to normal when he opens the menu (and closes it). But that's not how it should work and I need to fix it.

So what I need to do (I think) is make sure that the event wont trigger if one is already in progress (somehow). I tried some javascript function like delay() or setTimeout()... I tried to make functions out of the effects - unsuccessfully. I spent too much time on this and I'm out of ideas and skills needed to make this to work properly. Is anyone able to check the code for me and give some suggestion or maybe patch it?

**HERE'S THE CODE:**

HTML:

```
<div id="navigation_bar"> <!-- THE NAVIGATION BAR WITH ICON AND CAPTION HOLDER FOR THE TEXT -->
    <img id="menu_icon" src="<?= $base_url ?>public/web/images/menu.png">
    <p class="zatvorit">ZATVORIŤ</p>
    <p class="menu">MENU</p>
    <p class="caption_holder"><!-- HERE WILL THE MAGIC HAPPEN --></p> 

</div>
<div id="navigation_holder"> <!-- NOT IMPORTANT PART, ONLY THE MENU HOLDER AND MENU -->

    <p class="close_nav_mobile">
        <img src="<?= base_url() ?>public/web/images/close_menu.png">
    </p>

    <ul id="menu_item_list" class="">
        <li role="presentation"><a class="menu_1" href="<?= $base_url ?>nasa-ponuka">NAŠA PONUKA</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a class="menu_2" href="<?= $base_url ?>referencie">REFERENCIE</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a class="menu_3" href="<?= $base_url ?>kontakt">KONTAKT</a></li>
        <li id="order_link" class="menu_order_link order_form_open" role="presentation"><a href="#"><b>OBJEDNÁVKA</b></a></li>
        <li id="registration_link" class="menu_reg_form_link reg_form_open" role="presentation"><a href="#">REGISTRÁCIA</a></li>
    </ul>
        <a href="#"><img id="fb_icon" src="<?= $base_url ?>public/web/images/fb_icon.png"></a>
</div>
```

JavaScript & jQuery (magic stuff)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    menuOn = false; //is true when menu is opened

    //this makes the array of letters for 'MENU' caption
    captionMenu = $( "p.menu" ).text();
    var lettersMenu = [];
    lengthMenu = captionMenu.length;
    for (var i = 0; i <= lengthMenu - 1; i++) {
        lettersMenu[i] = captionMenu.charAt(i);
    };

    //this makes the array of letters for 'CLOSE' (acutally 'ZATVORIŤ') caption
    captionClose = $( "p.zatvorit" ).text();
    var lettersClose = [];
    lengthClose = captionClose.length;
    for (var i = 0; i <= lengthClose - 1; i++) {
        lettersClose[i] = captionClose.charAt(i);
    };

    //some variables to be able to check what's going on
    length = 0; //length of the caption we're working with
    captionMenuOn = false; //true when the 'MENU' caption is visible
    captionCloseOn = false; //true when the 'ZATBORIŤ' caption is visible
    j = 0; // how many letters have appeared already
    k = lengthMenu-1; //example of "how not to name your variables" but It should solve the off-by-one error

    //now the 'MENU' caption will appear letter by letter
    $(document).on("mouseenter", "#navigation_bar", function(){
        if(!menuOn && j==0) { //of course it won't be possible if the menu is opened and there are any letters left
            j = 0;
            length = lengthMenu; //we're working with 'MENU' now
            interval = 150 / length; //counts the interval depending on caption lenght
            for (var i = 0; i <= length - 1; i++) { //looping the letters
                $('p.caption_holder').delay(interval).queue(function (next) {
                    $(this).append( '<span class="caption_parcial_' + j + '">' + lettersMenu[j] + '</span>' );
                    j++; //a letter has appeared
                    if (j == length-1) { //if all the letters have appeared
                        captionMenuOn = true; //now you see me
                    }
                    next();
                });
            }
            k = lengthMenu - 1; //we should have 4 letters there somewhere
        }
    });

    //now the 'MENU' caption will disappear letter by letter an inverse event to that above
    $(document).on("mouseleave", "#navigation_bar", function(){
        if(!menuOn && k==lengthMenu-1) { //so the menu needs to be closed and the 'MENU' caption should be visible
            length = lengthMenu; //we're working with 'MENU' again
            interval = 150 / length;
            k = length;
            for (var i = 0; i <= length - 1; i++) {
                $('.caption_holder').delay(interval / 2).queue(function (next) {
                    k--; //a letter has disappeared
                    $('.caption_parcial_' + k).remove();
                    if (k == 0) { //if we have no letters left
                        captionMenuOn = false; //now you don't (see me)
                    }
                    next();
                });
            }
            j = 0; //we have 0 letters visible now
        }
    });

    //--------------------------------------THIS PART OPENS AND CLOSES THE MENU and resets the 'j' variable in case someone messed up the captions
    $(document).on("click", "#navigation_bar, .close_nav_mobile", function(){
        if(menuOn)
            $(".caption_holder").show();
        smallMenu();
    });

    $(document).on("click", ".menu_order_link", function(){
        smallMenu();
        j=0;
    });
    $(document).on("click", ".menu_reg_form_link", function(){
        smallMenu();
        j=0;
    });

        //function that opens or closes the menu
     function smallMenu() {

      if(!menuOn) { //if the menu is closed

       $("#menu_icon").attr("src", base_url + "public/web/images/close_menu.png").addClass("menu_close"); //icon changes
       //$("nav > ul").show();
            //the 'MENU' caption dissapears, we've seen this code before
          length = lengthMenu; 
          interval = 150 / length;
          j = length;
            for (var i = 0; i <= length - 1; i++) {
                $('.caption_holder').delay(interval / 2).queue(function (next) {
                    j--;
                    $('.caption_parcial_' + j).remove();
                    //and the 'CLOSE' caption will appear right away
                    if (j == 0) {
                        captionMenuOn = false;
                        length = lengthClose; //now we're working with 'CLOSE' caption
                        interval = 150 / length;
                        j = 0;
                        for (var i = 0; i <= length - 1; i++) {
                            $('p.caption_holder').delay(interval).queue(function (next) {
                                $(this).append( '<span class="caption_parcial_' + j + '">' + lettersClose[j] + '</span>' );
                                j++;
                                if (j == length-1) {
                                    captionCloseOn = true;
                                }
                                next();
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    next();
                });
            }



            /*
       $("#navigation_holder").animate(
             {
                 'left' : '0%'
             }, 1250, 'easeOutExpo' );*/

        $("#navigation_holder").css("left", "0%"); //and the menu shows

        menuOn = true; //the menu is opened

      }
      else { //if the menu is opened

       $("#menu_icon").attr("src", base_url + "public/web/images/menu.png").removeClass("menu_close"); //changing icon
            //we need to hide the 'CLOSE' caption
          length = lengthClose; 
          interval = 150 / length;
          j = length;
          for (var i = 0; i <= length - 1; i++) {
              $('.caption_holder').delay(interval / 2).queue(function (next) {
                  j--;
                  $('.caption_parcial_' + j).remove();
                  if (j == 0) {
                      captionCloseOn = false;
                  }
                  next();
              });
          }

       /*
       $("#navigation_holder").animate(
             {
                 'left' : '-50%'
             }, 1250, 'easeOutExpo' );*/

             //and hide the menu
        if($(".mobile_nav").is(":visible")) {
            $("#navigation_holder").css("left", "-100%");
        } else {
            $("#navigation_holder").css("left", "-50%");
        }



       menuOn = false; //now the menu is closed

      }


     }


    //NOT IMPORTANT
     $(window).resize(function() {

        if(!menuOn) {

            if($(".mobile_nav").is(":visible")) {
                $("#navigation_holder").css("left", "-100%");
            } else {
                $("#navigation_holder").css("left", "-50%");
            }

        }

     });


</script>
```

CSS (in case you want to run it on your localhost properly):

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Biryani:400,700,300,600);


* {
    font-family: 'Biryani', sans-serif !important;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body, html {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:100%;
}

body {
  overflow-x:hidden;
}


/*---------------------------NAVIGATION------------------------*/


#navigation_bar {
  width: 55px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1500;
}

#menu_icon {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 49%;
}

.zatvorit {
  display: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-family: "BauerBodoniDOT-Regular", serif !important;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: -11px;
margin-top: -74px;
}

.menu {
  display: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-family: "BauerBodoniDOT-Regular", serif !important;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 42%;
  left: 6px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.menu_close {
  max-width: 18px !important;
}

.caption_holder {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-family: "BauerBodoniDOT-Regular", serif !important;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 3px;
  margin-top: -59px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: left;
}

.right_buttons {
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  right: 55px;
}

.caption_holder span {
  font-family: "BauerBodoniDOT-Regular", serif !important;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

#navigation_holder {
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: right;
  z-index: 1000;
  left: -50%;
      transition:all ease 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition:all ease 0.5s;
    -moz-transition:all ease 0.5s;
    -o-transition:all ease 0.5s;
}
```

**THANKS FOR HELP AND SUGGESTIONS! :)**

Comment: TL; DR - Read [ask]!

Comment: use a flag set by the first event, and checked for by every event.

Comment: Worth having a read through [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and *[mcve]*

Comment: Add a `onclick="return false;"` attribute to your element first thing in the function handling the event, and remove it at the  end of that function.

Comment: just a general tip - if you need to deal with text animations I suggest using a ready third-party lib, like textillate.js which is pretty easy to use.

Comment: I'd put this in jsfiddle.net first so others can play with it to help you out rather than forcing the person who wants to help you set up the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

Use **SEMAPHOR** pattern, with variable named `locked` which is `false` if event's action is stopped (finished):

```
var locked_mouseenter=false; //initialize "UNLOCK"
$(document).on("mouseenter", "#navigation_bar", function(){
    if( !locked_mouseenter ){
        locked_mouseenter = true; //lock

        // you code here of event's action

        // code stop here, so the next instruction is : 
        locked_mouseenter = false; //unlock
    }
});
```